# Spring Boot Web App in executable jar - How can customers supply independent jdbc driver?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, classpath, executable-jar

I'm building a web app using spring boot with the goal of having an executable jar that customers can just run without the hassle of deploying to a tomcat web server.

This web app uses a jdbc database connection and customers can use a database of their choosing by simply supplying a jdbc driver jar.

However executable jars do not allow to use of -cp or -classpath, so how can  customers best supply their jdbc database driver jar to my spring boot web app? Has anybody experienced a similar issue and found a work around for this without packaging every possible jdbc driver into the web app jar?

Comment: Instead of using executable JAR write a script/batch file and setup class path in there. This script should be used to run the application, that's how it's done for the most applications for example: Tomcat, Karaf, Maven. If you don't want to do that then you can dynamically load the driver JAR file. Show a popup to user to select the JAR and ask him to select the driver class in there, it's done in the Squirrel SQL client. It's opensource, so may be you can recycle come code from it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Spring Boot's `PropertiesLauncher` and its `loader.path property` to point to an external directory into which JDBC driver jars could be added by your users. You can learn more about `PropertiesLauncher` and its `loader.path` property in [Spring Boot's reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features).